# How can I update the territories in which my existing app is available on Appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I have an App on Apple App Store, which is available in the US and the UK store, but I want to make it available for all territories(stores) . How can I do that ? Should I post a new version or can it be changed immediately ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can immediately change the territories in which your app is available. Well, not immediately, but within a few hours it'll be changed. To do so you have to go under **Apps > YourApp > Pricing**. 
[image: Itunes Connect Page]
Here on the lower part of page it will say:

> Unless you **select specific** territories, your app will be available for sale in all App Store Volume Purchase Program territories.

Click the select specific territories button, and the press the checkbox next to select all. This will allow you to release the app to everywhere in the world. Save and exit.

Hope that helps, Julian